# :hover wont change child's font color

Tags: html, css

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f33cR/)

So yeah, the `<b>` should change `font-color` whenever hovered but it doesnt. The thing is, I am able to make it work by either

- Removing #`sidebar` in the stylesheet (i.e. `#sidebar nav#menu`)
- or by removing `#menu` in `nav#menu` in the stylesheet

But why does this happen?

Also, bonus question, how come the border animation only activates on mouseover but not on mouseout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is getting changed but your initial color is overriding the current one.

You can do

```
#yourelement:hover b{ color: red !important;}
```

Comment: That made perfect sense! I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/f33cR/
Check this

Note : When you add a class like "#paren #child #element" then you apply a simple css like #element dosen't overwrite that class. If you want to overwrite you have two option.

Option 1. `#parent #child #element:hover`

or

Option 2. `#element:hover { color:red!important;}`

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use !important in your CSS because of the way you've written your CSS it won't overwrite the default, predefined colour.

A fast & dirty (but works) alternative is to simply move `color: #555` from `<b>` into the `li`

http://jsfiddle.net/f33cR/8/

Answer (score 0):

**Write your css as like this**

```
#sidebar nav#menu #home-btn:hover b { color:#ef672f; }
#sidebar nav#menu #about-btn:hover b { color:#1ba59b; }
#sidebar nav#menu #portfolio-btn:hover b { color:#4d7ba2; }
#sidebar nav#menu #resume-btn:hover b { color:#bc6538;}
#sidebar nav#menu #contact-btn:hover b { color:#79a22e; }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f33cR/2/)**

### ---------------

**2nd option is please**

**replace this**

```
#sidebar nav#menu li b { font-size:1.7em;  text-align:left; color:#555; }
```

**into this**

```
nav#menu li b { font-size:1.7em;  text-align:left; color:#555; }
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/f33cR/6/)**

Comment: Thanks! But how come it doesn't work without the '#sidebar nav#menu'? shouldnt it work without it? Like how the border worked without it?

Comment: becuse id value is more than high class

Comment: more info go to this link http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this

```
#sidebar nav#menu #home-btn:hover b { color:#ef672f; }
#sidebar nav#menu #about-btn:hover b { color:#1ba59b; }
#sidebar nav#menu #portfolio-btn:hover b { color:#4d7ba2; }
#sidebar nav#menu #resume-btn:hover b { color:#bc6538;}
#sidebar nav#menu #contact-btn:hover b { color:#79a22e; }
```

About the bonus, I don't know but you can better trigger that actions with jquery.

Comment: Thanks! I already figured that out though. I don't know what causes it not to work without the parent IDs when the border worked out fine without them

Comment: That's, as the answer you've chosen says, you have to change that stuff to work, and also mark it with !important if you want. But choose the one you want.